# bitwise and logical AND/OR in terms of hex result

Tags: bitwise-operators, logical-operators, bitwise-and, bitwise-or

so if I have `x = 0x01` and `y = 0xff` and I do `x & y`, I would get `0x01`. If I do `x && y` do I still get `0x01`, but the computer just says its true if its anything than `0x00`? My question is are the bits the same after the operation regardless of bit-wise or logical AND/OR, but the computer just interprets the final result differently? In other words are the hex values of the result of & and && (likewise | and ||) operations the same?

edit: talking about C here

Comment: If you want a definitive answer then you'll need to specify a language.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the precise language in use.

In some weakly-typed languages (e.g. Perl, JavaScript) `a && b` will evaluate to the actual value of `b` if both `a` and `b` are "truthy", or `a` otherwise.

In C and C++ the `&&` operator will just return 0 or 1, i.e. the `int` equivalent of `true` or false.

In Java and C# it's not even legal to supply an `int` to `&&` - the operands must already be booleans.

I don't know of any language off the top of my head where `a && b == a & b` for all legal values of `a` and `b`.

Comment: This particular question if for C. I have a question where I have to fill the hex values for a given x and y(mask). So even if I have `x = 0x0a && y = 0x7`, the result will be 0x01? Not 0x06? I thought with && its false if 0 and true if anything else

Comment: Yup, it'll be `0x01`, that is `(int)true`

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the operators behave differently:
&& is only allowed for boolean types and & for any integer type as well.

a && b returns true, if both a and b are true.
a & b returns the result of the bitwise AND operation.