# Understanding calculations in JS using bitwise AND, OR, and hex numbers

Tags: javascript, math, hex, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to understand a piece of code shared here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117523/2586761

```js
// returns a valid GUID
'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0;
    var v = c === 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
});
// "3bce4931-6c75-41ab-afe0-2ec108a30860"
```

I understand from the question [Using bitwise OR 0 to floor a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487977/using-bitwise-or-0-to-floor-a-number) that a `3.142 | 0` will return an integer by truncating the fraction, but I'm guessing when it comes to applying this to hex numbers, and lost when we AND then OR like: `randomNumber & 0x3 | 0x8`.

I've discovered that a hex value has a `toString` method (a number doesn't!):

```
0x3.toString() // returns '3'
```

And I'm guessing that maybe `randomNumber & 0x3 | 0x8` is returning a two bit value which is an ascii character (not just a number) in the desired range... but I'm guessing, and I can't find a nice reference which gives me the whole picture.

Can anyone step me through it / suggest a reference?

This question seems related, but doesn't deal with JS specifically, or match my example: [bitwise and logical AND/OR in terms of hex result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282002/bitwise-and-logical-and-or-in-terms-of-hex-result)

---

### Update:

I've since notice that there are a bunch of great answers on the original question which explore the question, in particular https://stackoverflow.com/a/28921801/2586761, but none of them answer all my questions..

In particular, how does a number get converted to a character without using something like `String.fromCharCode()`?

Comment: Great question!  Also for the record, numbers do have a `toString` method:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString

Comment: gold, thanks @SimianAngel! I was missing the parens and radix: `(42).toString(16) // "2a"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, neither `&` nor `|` performs conversion to an ASCII character, this conversion is performed by the last `v.toString(16)`. `&` and `|` just do bitwise operations.

Before the second line of the function, `r` contains a random integer number between `0x0` and `0xf`. It can be represented with four bits: `r` == abcd, where a, b, c and d are 0 or 1.

`r & 0x3` nullifies everything except for two latter bits (since 3 is binary 11). So, `r & 0x3` == 00cd.

`| 0x8` sets the first bit (since 8 is binary 1000). So, `r & 0x3 | 0x8` == 10cd.

As a result, the whole expression `r & 0x3 | 0x8` takes two least significant bits of `r` and appends them to binary 10. Before this operation we could have any number from 0x0 to 0xf, but after it only four variants are possible: 0x8 (binary 1000), 0x9 (binary 1001), 0xa (binary 1010) or 0xb (binary 1011).

Comment: fantastic, thanks.. I've nearly got it.. can you explain how the four variations `1000, 1001, 1010, 1011` get translated to a random alphanumeric? `(1011).toString(16) // '3f3'`

Comment: Each of these four variations is just one hexadecimal symbol: 1000 is '8', 1001 is '9', 1010 is 'a', and 1011 is 'b'.

The whole random string is generated by the starting string with a lot of x's and some y's. The algorithm substitutes a random digit (in the whole range from 0 to f) for any x and one of these four options in place of y.

Comment: ah, now I understand, in the Y position, only those four characters are allowed by the spec.. also.. I was under the mistaken impression that the characters produced were `[a-z-0-9]`, but now I understand that only hex values are produced.. mystery solved! Many thanks!